# No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema could be loaded

Tags: osgi, cxf, dosgi, aegis

When trying to expose a Service with Aegis databinding in CXF DOSGi I get this error in Java 8. In java 7 it works fine.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema could be loaded
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.XMLTypeCreator.(XMLTypeCreator.java:122)

[See full stacktrace here](http://apaste.info/8TO)

I think the reason is that the code does not see the impl class `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Btw. the exception can be observed by running the CXF-DOSGi build in Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not have found a real solution for this. For now I have committed a workaround on CXF master to ignore this exception in the static code. So the Aegis binding is not schema checked but at least works. See [CXF-6959](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6959).

I would be happy about any hints to get this fully working again.